# Can't create a web app with .NET Core 3.1 on Visual Studio (Mac)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm brand new to Visual Studio IDE and learning C#. I'm following Microsoft's [Web apps/Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac) Tutorial and i've already installed Visual Studio and dotnet 3.1

I'm attempting to start a new project but for some reason I can't seem to click the "create" button. Nothing happens. I am able to create a project with `3.0` but this causes some versioning issues with eventual packages that I'll be installing.

Here's information on my dotnet versioning:

```
dotnet --info

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  65f04fb6db

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

And here is where the project creation is halted:

[image: Project creation stall]

Comment: When you run the project is throwing an error?

Comment: There's no error, I simply cannot "create" a project. Doesn't let me click it. However, it works fine when I change my .NET Core version to 3.0 in the previous step.

Comment: What's version of VS for Mac you use? The latest 16.4 comes with .NET Core 3.1, but old versions won't.

Comment: I'm using the latest one that's on the main site. It's the stable 8.3.11 version which comes with .NET Core 3.1  This is driving me crazy, idk why I can't click on the "create" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Mac will only support .net core 3.1 with the new version 8.4.
You can switch the update channel to preview and do the updates. After installing the preview updates the creation of projects with .net core 3.1 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done as a workaround is create the project as dotnet core 3.0. And then simply edit the csproj files to target 3.1:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```